# Why did Ronald Knox from Black Butler say that the passengers of the Campania died from heart failure? Shouldn't it be hemorrhaging?

Tags: black-butler

I was reading chapter 56 of Kuroshitsuji, and Ronald Knox describes the cause of death of the Campania passengers as "heart failure."

Shouldn't it be more accurate to put in blood loss/hemorrhaging?